# Derivation formula for sum including newton symbol

Tags: summation, proof-writing, solution-verification

So i was  asked to derive formula for given sum:

> $$ {n\choose0} +\frac 12 {n\choose1}+\frac 13{n\choose2}+...+\frac 1{n+1}{n\choose n}         $$

So i made few attempts, but not for all steps i'm sure that are correct.

1. $S=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k+1}{n\choose k}             $
2. $ S(n+1)=   \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n+1}{k+1}{n\choose k}=   \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1\choose k+1}          \quad  $
3. $S(n+1)=2^{n+1}-1           $
4. So $S  =\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}   $

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is indeed correct, though it took me a second to realize $S(n+1)$ was $S\times(n+1)$.

Comment: Nice idea to multiply by $n+1$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is both elegant and correct! Here's another way:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 1 {k + 1}{n \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\int_0^1x^kdx=\int_0^1(1+x)^ndx=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Just   a     small variation   of  OP's  approach.

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{n}{j}}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+1}{j+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p+1}{q+1}=\frac{p+1}{q+1}\binom{p}{q}$.
- In (2)  we shift the  index and start with $j=1$.
- In  (3)   we   apply the  binomial theorem.